# overloading list comprehension mechanism in Python

Tags: python, list, overloading, list-comprehension

Advanced question:
Say, you create a class that acts like a list but with fast searching for an element, i.e a list that also indexes its content elements, so that finding the index of a particular element is O(1), as opposed to O(n), as in a standard list.  Then how do you do the following?

```
class Fast_List():
  def __init__(self):
    self._list = []
    self._index = {}

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return self._list[idx]

  def __call__(self, idx):
    return self._list[idx]

  def append(self, elem):
    idx = len(self._list)
    self._list.append(elem)
    self._index[elem] = idx

  def index(self, elem):
    return self._index[elem]

al = Fast_List()

al = [i**2 for i in range(1000)]
```

The last line in the above code will create a regular list, not a Fast_list, of consecutive integer squares.
**But what if I want it to return the Fast_List version of the comprehension statement**
(of course, I am missing some function definitions in my class above but it should not cloud the question I am asking

Now, of course, I am aware that I can simply use the for loop to build my Fast_List

```
al = Fast_List()
for i in range(1000):
  al.append(i**2)
```

... but I like the comprehension mechanism and I am wondering if it can be applied to create user-defined class objects

Comment: There is no way to make a list comprehension not evaluate to a list. That is what the construct does

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Here's a list comprehension that doesn't evaluate to a list: `[1/x for x in range(666)]`.

Comment: @superbrain running into an error while constructing a list is still constructing a list.

Comment: @rdas I agree with "construct" but not with "evaluate".

Comment: @superbrain Perhaps "Always evaluates to a list if it completes without errors" would be more accurate but that's splitting hairs at this point. Either way, it's unhelpful to the discussion at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Add an alternate constructor to your `Fast_List` and call that on the result of the list comprehension.

```py
class Fast_List():
  def __init__(self):
    self._list = []
    self._index = {}

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    return self._list[idx]

  def __call__(self, idx):
    return self._list[idx]

  def append(self, elem):
    idx = len(self._list)
    self._list.append(elem)
    try:
      self._index[elem].append(idx)
    except KeyError:
      self._index[elem] = [idx]

  def index(self, elem):
    list_idx = self._index[elem]
    return list_idx

  @classmethod
  def from_list(cls, lst):
    self = cls()
    for el in lst:
      self.append(el)
    return self
```

```py
result = Fast_List.from_list([i**2 for i in range(1000)])
```

Now you might say: "Well sure, but I'm still constructing the list before ingesting it into `Fast_List`," and that would be true. However you don't *need* this to be a list for any reason. Change the parameters around and use a genexp instead and suddenly you can omit the list initialization entirely.

```py
  # inside Fast_List(), literally just a rename of from_list to from_iterable
  # and lst to iterable

  @classmethod
  def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
    self = cls()
    for el in iterable:
      self.append(el)
    return self

# and in the construction, literally just omit the square brackets
result = Fast_List.from_list(i**2 for i in range(1000))
```

in fact, you might notice that you could just optionally initialize `Fast_List` this way to begin with! Let's do that:

```py
class Fast_List():
    def __init__(self, iterable=None):
        self._list = []
        self._index = {}
        if iterable is not None:
            for el in iterable:
                self.append(el)
    # the rest of the class is unchanged

result = Fast_List(i**2 for i in range(1000))
```

Comment: Alternatively, an optional argument to the `__init__` method that can be a list which will reduce the code to simply `Fast_List([i**2 for i in range(1000)])`

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, coming so quick after me posting the question.  But your solution still has the issue of creating a regular list first and then converting it to Fast_List.  Is there a way of doing it directly to avoid doubling of mem needed to generate the Fast_List?  (seems like everything in Python can be overloaded, so how about overloading the comprehension mechanism?)

Comment: @ChrisWysocki did you read my whole answer? I literally anticipated your question :)

Comment: and we have the answer.  You guys are the best!  Thanks Mr. Smith